# Hide/Show custom dialog in Android

Tags: android

I have a custom dialog which is non-modal. In my screen i have custom dialog and few other UI elements. user taps on the dialog and it is shown. Now i want to handle a scenario where if he/she clicks anywhere on other UI elements i want to hide the dialog.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener to the UI element and use this when a user clicks it.

public final void dismissDialog (int id)

Since: API Level 1
Dismiss a dialog that was previously shown via showDialog(int).
Parameters

id  The id of the managed dialog.